# Random Errors in kubuntu with boot, ACPI and audio drivers

Tags: boot, nvidia, sound, kubuntu, acpi

After a few weeks installing kubuntu, I started seeing some random errors while booting, shutting down or restarting.

Sometimes the error happens when booting. First, after passing the grub screen, the kubuntu glowing screen appears. Then for a few seconds the laptop OEM logo appears! Sometimes, the boot process gets stuck in the OEM logo and then tells me it has ACPI error. I have put `acpi=strict` in the boot parameters to no avail. The screen is stuck with this error on it:

```
_CRS returned 0
... previous line repeats 7 times
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PGON due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200528/psparse-529)
ACPI Error: Aborting method \_SB.PCIO.PEGO.PGOO._ON due to previous error (AE_AML_LOOP_TIMEOUT) (20200528/psparse-529)
```

Second, randomly when shutting down or restarting, the system doesn't shut down but rather goes into `nvidia-modeset` error. It says

```
nvidia-modeset - error waiting for GPU process - [random number]
```

These errors do not occur once I reboot. The OEM logo still shows up but the system successfully logs in. But, sometimes the audio drivers don't work after I boot my system like this. Its sometimes the microphone, sometimes the speaker, sometimes both (both in-built).

Both of these devices don't even get recognized. The system just pretends like it doesn't have a mic or a speaker. But, whenever I reboot, it all comes back.

I don't know if it's all related somehow but, if it isn't, i'm happy to post it as a separate question too.

Comment: What is the Kubuntu version? What is the hardware?

Comment: @Pilot6
Kubuntu 20.10
Laptop Asus ROG Strix Gt531gt
Nvidia 1650TI, Intel i7 9650h, 16GB ram

BTW, I solved it by installing [bumblebee](https://bumblebee-project.org/). Turns out the graphics card was taking care of xorg but since there was no optimus support, It must have failed to switch to integrated gpu.